# Composing Overwrite (merge) type operator

Tags: typescript

Trying to compose `Overwrite` type operator, which should take keys from first operand type and replace them with the keys from second (aka object `merge` operation):

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[P] } & U

type A = {

  a?: number,
  d: boolean
  b: string
}

type B = {  
  b: number
}

type C = Overwrite<A, B> = {
  a: number | undefined; // not optinal anymore
  d: boolean;
} & B
```

Optinal key `a` from first operand `A` becomes required (though with `undefined` value possible)

Is it possible to leave it optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the built in `Pick` type instead of creating your own mapped type. Something like:

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U
```

That will preserve any modifiers on `T`, such as readonly or optional, whereas using a custom mapped type will remove those modifiers[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724826/composing-overwrite-merge-type-operator/50725161?noredirect=1#comment88458836_50725161).

When using that type with your example:

```
declare const test: Overwrite<A, B>;
test.a // (property) a?: number (note: still optional, no undefined union)
test.b // (property) b: number
test.c // (property) d: boolean
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Overwrite%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20U%3E%3E%20%26%20U%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20a%3F%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20d%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20test%3A%20Overwrite%3CA%2C%20B%3E%3B%0D%0Atest.a%0D%0Atest.b%0D%0Atest.d%0D%0A)

Comment: "using a custom mapped type will remove those modifiers" isn't true in general (after all, `Pick<>` is just part of the standard library and isn't special-cased by the compiler) but it is true that there is [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24679#issuecomment-394710628) with using conditional types and mapped types this way that is circumvented by using a layer of indirection like `Pick<>`.